# How to fix the panel indicator display errors?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, indicator, compiz, gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [panel items look weird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4103/panel-items-look-weird)

How do I fix this error? I know this can be done by restarting the panel, but this is not convenient because every time you boot you need to do it.

[image: Screenshot of panel artefacts]

Comment: I also have this problem. Looks like a common bug, someone submit to launchpad?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug for this one already:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/660877

It doesn't have any other people saying anything in it, so I'm not sure whether it is known to the devs. I have had a look for a fix, and it seems like this will work:

create ".gtkrc-2.0" file in your home firectory, and put this in it:

```
include "/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
gtk-icon-theme-name = "ubuntu-mono-dark"
```

Hope this fixes it for you :-)

Comment: There is also https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/623001

Comment: This error has been reported to lunchpad.net version 10.04 but no one was able to help. Drivers, the new compiz, nothing helped. Useful to the script at startup which panel would restarted but it is not so simple. I wrote the script and added it to autostart but not working properly.