# Can't connect in Eduroam anymore

Tags: 18.04, wireless

My laptop have Ubuntu 18.04. I used to connect normally to Eduroam(WPA/PEAP) wifi, but since a few days I can't. I tried many things I saw in forums

https://askubuntu.com/questions/7884...ing-to-eduroam

Even I found in one of them, what is happening exactly in my case: connect Eduroam in one building but not in other. I read in the forums that this kind of enterprise internet have different channel and yes I can connect in some others but the problem is the weak signal.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...r/+bug/1748839

I read some people downgrade wpa_supplicant to 2.4 or 2.1 version, does it really help?

Please, If you could give some ideas to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Before downgrading anything on your own machine, the one thing I would suggest is this; when you move around, from A to B, actively log off the wifi in A, move to B and re-log on. It may seem a little over kill but I haver found this long handed way of doing things has worked for me. I've never really worked out if Ubuntu is not working with the rest of the world, or if the rest of world is not working with Ubuntu. But the "switch it off/on" solution may have some success.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show you interesting log messages. For even more, remove the `-b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I tried different things as in forums, really reset NetworkManager.  As I said eduroam connected in one place but not in others, after type sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager   It reconnects. If that command it is just for log It has not much sense, I am affraid to have this problem again.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, if it happens again I will post with log messages with that command.