# No shut down button in my panel

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Visual corruption affecting several panel applets](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4103/visual-corruption-affecting-several-panel-applets)

I have following bug in my panel which occurs randomly, but not always, and sometimes bother me. Sometimes the shut down button just disappears in the panel, like it is in the picture below.

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestion would be considered valuable.